# SQLite - Index of record

Tags: sql, sqlite

To describe my problem, I have created the following database:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Town
(
  IdTown integer PRIMARY KEY ASC,
  Name TEXT
);
```

Records:

```
IdTown  Name
1870    Brighlingsea
8723    Chelmsford
2263    Clacton on Sea
1263    Colchester
3299    Gt. Yarmouth
6565    Harwich
9526    Ipswich
9961    Kelverdon
7263    Manningtree
3589    Norwich
3647    Witham
6632    Wivenhoe
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to write a query that returns the index position of the record that contains a specific primary key value whilst the records are sorted in name order.

For example, if I pass in an IdTown of 9961 it will return 8 because Kelverdon is the 8th record when sorted in Name order.

In SQL Server (which I am more familiar with) I would use a query like this:

```
select Position
from
(
    select IdTown, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS position
    from   Town
) s1
where s1.IdTown = 9961
```

Does anyone know a way I can do this in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery to get the name for the id, and then count the rows having a name less than or equal to that name:

```
select count(*) as position
from town t
where t.name <= (select t2.name from t2 where t2.idtown = 9961)
```

Comment: Man was about to say you can't do it, but that's brilliant!